# How does one list the available Calendars Names and their UID using Apple Script?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to write a Apple Script to list the names of the Calendars accessible in the macOS Calendar App. Anyone can advise on how to do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this:

```
tell application "Calendar"
    set {calendarNames, calendarIDs} to {name, uid} of every calendar
end tell
```

Comment: JSYK... In  **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** this fails with '**error** "Calendar got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000' as it appears that **Apple** has removed the `uid` _property_ from a _calendar_.

Comment: @user3439894 This is quite odd. I see `calendarIdentifier` as a property of `calendar` in the dictionary, but I get that error when I try to retrieve it. Also, when I type `calendarIdentifier` into the ScriptEditor it is automagically rewritten to `uid`.
I'd also be curious to know if we can tell the difference between the various calendar types through AppleScript

Answer (score 1):

Scriptable applications have a dictionary of the terminology they provide that can be opened in the Script Editor by using the **File > Open Dictionary...** menu item.  Looking in its scripting dictionary, you will see that the Calendar *application* class contains *calendar* elements, which have a *name* property, so you can just do something like:

```
tell application "Calendar"
    get name of calendars
end tell
```